# Simplest way to send an object from PHP to iOS

Tags: xml, ios, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHTPTRequest on the iPhone to pick up some objects from a web server. I'm doing the following:

1. Make a request from the iPhone using ASIHTTPRequest.
2. The web server running PHP generates an XML representation of my object.
3. The iPhone reads it, parses the XML, and generates my custom object.

This works but seems to be a lot of work for something that should be simpler (I think).

**Is there a way to make this process more efficient?**

At some point I will need to do the opposite too (generate XML on the iPhone and send it to the web server running PHP) but haven't got there yet... I'm not particularly fond of XML and will be happy to change formats if there is anything that will work better for this kind of situation.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using JSON as an alternative to XML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is within the scope of your question, but if you're not a fan of XML, you might be tempted to look at JSON, as it's:

1. Well supported in PHP via [json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode)/[json_decode](http://www.php.net/json_decode).
2. Well supported under iOS via the [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) project.

Comment: This looks very promising indeed! I'll take JSON over XML any day. I'm going to mark this question as answered but let me throw you an extra question: How does the JSON parser know what kind of Objective-C object to create?

Comment: @Julian I've not looked at the specifics, but it's always created an object of the appropriate type from what I can remember. (Used it a while back, so it's not that fresh in my mind - apologies.)

Comment: I've given it a shot and using ASIHTTPRequest + TouchJSON could do what I wanted in 10 lines of code or so (make a request and turn that into one or more objects). Thank you!